# Python: Would vectorization/broadcasting boost speed?

Tags: python, loops, numpy, vectorization, array-broadcasting

**GOAL:** Merge arrays p1 to p10 to create one large array named 'a' and return all values in 'a' that appear in 'a', 4 times.

**Question:** This code is super slow because of all the looping to be done, How can I make it swifter? Would vectorization and/or broadcasting aid in efficiency (Is it possible to get rid of all that looping) ? Or any other out of the box ideas for swiftness?

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
from numba import jit

p1 = np.random.randint(0,314000,200000)
p2 = np.random.randint(0,314000,100000)
p3 = np.random.randint(0,314000,300000)
p4 = np.random.randint(0,314000,150000)
p5 = np.random.randint(0,314000,220000)
p6 = np.random.randint(0,314000,320000)
p7 = np.random.randint(0,314000,212100)
p8 = np.random.randint(0,314000,100500)
p9 = np.random.randint(0,314000,300700)
p10 = np.random.randint(0,314000,200300)

@jit
def count(a,n):
 counters=np.zeros(10**6,np.int32)
 for i in a:
  counters[i] += 1
 res=np.empty_like(counters)
 k = 0    
 for i,j in enumerate(counters):
  if j == n:
   res[k] = i
   k += 1
 return res[:k]        


for t in range(0, 20000):
 a = itertools.chain(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10)
 count(a,4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and yes. You can get rid of the loops and it will speed up things:

```
>>> a = np.concatenate([p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10])
>>> np.flatnonzero(np.bincount(a, minlength=314000)==4)
array([    29,     33,     38, ..., 313944, 313949, 313973])
```

Comment: This is awesome, Thanks Paul! The speed up is immense.